# Probability of a rational nearest neighbor of an irrational

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider the following distribution over $(X, Y) \in [0,1] \times \{0, 1\}$:

$\mathbb{P}(Y = 0) = \mathbb{P}(Y = 1) = 1/2$

If $Y = 0$ then $X$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $[0, 1]$

If $Y = 1$ then $X$ is distributed over the rationals in $[0, 1]$ such that each rational has positive probability (for example, consider $Z = \min(A, B)/\max(A,B)$ for $A,B$ with geometric distribution)

Show that for any irrational $x \in [0, 1]$, the nearest neighbor (call it $NN_n(x)$) to $x$ in a set of $n$ draws of $X_i$ from the distribution above is such that as $n \rightarrow \infty$:

$$\mathbb{P}(NN_n(x) \, \text{is rational}) \rightarrow 0$$

**What I've Tried**

Listing the probabilities for increasing values of $n$:

For $n = 1$ it is obvious:
$$\mathbb{P}(NN_1(x) \, \text{is rational}) = \mathbb{P}(X_i \, \text{is rational}) = 1/2$$
For $n = 2$ it is more difficult. My initial thought is to consider all orderings of the $n$ samples. The orderings can't be equally likely since then we have a probability of $1/2$ for all $n$. I think there is some measure theoretic concept I am missing.

It's also clear to me that when $Y=0$, $X$ is irrational wp 1, since the set of rationals have measure $0$.

EDIT: The following has some issues (see the discussion in the comments)

Another thought I had is that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(NN_n(x) \, \text{is rational}) \leq \mathbb{P}(NN_n(x) \, \text{is rational infinitely often})$$

We can show the probability on the RHS is $0$ by showing that $\|NN_n(x) - x\| \rightarrow 0$ almost surely:

First note that the event $\{\|NN_n(x) - x\| > \varepsilon\}$ is equivalent to the event $\{1/n \sum_i^n\mathbb{I}(\|X_i - x\| \leq \varepsilon) = 0\}$. By the strong law of large numbers,  wp $1$:

$$ \frac 1 n \sum_i^n\mathbb{I}(\|X_i - x\| \leq \varepsilon) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\|X_i - x\| \leq \varepsilon)$$

Since the ball around $x$ has positive support, the event $\{1/n \sum_i^n\mathbb{I}(\|X_i - x\| \leq \varepsilon) = 0\}$ has probability $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Given that this event is equivalent to $\{\|NN_n(x) - x\| > \varepsilon\}$, then $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \|NN_n(x) - x\| > \varepsilon) = 0$ as was desired.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly why you know $\mathbb P(NN_n(x)\ \text{is rational infinitely often}) = 0$?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I added some details, hopefully that's more clear now.

Comment: Yes but why does it matter if $\lvert NN_n(x) - x \rvert \to 0$ almost surely? That doesn't say anything about if $NN_n(x)$ is rational or irrational.

Comment: I know $x$ is irrational, so the claimed convergence shows that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}NN_n(x)$ is irrational almost surely. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, knowing that $\lim_{n \to \infty} NN_n(x)$ is irrational doesn't tell you the $NN_n(x)$ themselves are rational or irrational. Rational numbers can tend to an irrational limit.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I realize a sequence of rationals can have an irrational limit, but my claim is that since the nearest neighbor cannot be rational infinitely often, there is some $m$ such that for all $n \geq m$ the nearest neighbor is irrational. So then in the limit the nearest neighbor is irrational. I dont care about any specific nearest neighbor, only the limit.

Comment: But you're trying to prove that the nearest neighbor cannot be rational infinitely often, that's not your starting assumption

Comment: Now I see the distinction, thanks.

Comment: I think @MarcusM's answer is correct. For any given $x$, you can put some of the probability on a sequence of rationals that rapidly converge to $x$.  If $x$ were uniformly drawn (or any other continuous distribution), then I'm pretty sure your conjecture is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.  For the case of $Y = 1$ I'll define the law of $X$ as follows: with probability $1/2$ it is equal to some distribution taking each rational with positive probability and with $1/2$ it is equal to $Z$ where $$P(Z = 1/n^n) = 2^{-n}$$ for each $n \geq 2$.  I claim that for $x = 0$ and $n$ large enough, the nearest neighbor will be a rational number with high probability.

I'll just show it for, e.g. $n = 3^m$ for $m$ large.  There will with high probability at least, say, $3^{m-1}$ samples with $Y = 1$ and $3^{m-2}$ with $X$ sampled from $Z$; let $N$ be this number.  The number of samples of $Z$ equal to $1/m^m$ is a binomial variable with success parameter $2^{-m}$ and $N \geq 3^{m-2}$ samples and so with high probability there is some $Z = 1/m^m$.

However, even if you sample all $3^m$ uniformly from $[0,1]$ the probability that some sample lies in $[0,1/m^m]$ is bounded above by $3^m/m^m$ which tends to zero.  Thus, the point closest to $0$ must be some sample from the case of $Y = 1$, i.e. a rational.

---

EDIT: How to generalize this to arbitrary $x \in [0,1]$.  For each $n \geq 2$ find rational number $x_n$ so that $|x - x_n| \leq 1/n^n$.  Then, define the law $Z$ to be $$P(Z = x_n) = 2^{-n}$$ for all $n \geq 2$.  The argument then goes through exactly the same way: for $n = 3^m$ with high probability there is some sample of $x_m$ and no samples from the uniform distribution in $[x - m^{-m}, x+ m^{-m}]$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you consider $0$ as an irrational number?

Comment: Haha my apologies I missed that, but I suspect this does not matter.  I'll edit my answer to make this work.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the argument, but I'd be surprised if this is false (unless of course I've asked a different question than I think I'm asking). In particular because the binary classification problem associated with this distribution has Bayes risk of $0$ and so also has a nearest neighbor risk of $0$.

Comment: Have you shown that the nearest neighbor of a rational tends to a rational with probability $1$? What I'm after is showing that the nearest neighbor of an irrational tends to an irrational with probability $1$.

Comment: I've shown that for *any* $x \in [0,1]$---rational or irrational---you can choose the law of $X$ so that the probability the nearest neighbor is rational tends to 1.

Comment: Could you clarify why this is equivalent to the case I've described above? In the edit you specify the law of $Z$ based on the $x$ chosen, but in my case the law is fixed beforehand.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not proving that *for every* law $X$ and *every* $x$ the nearest neighbor asymptotically is a rational.  I'm providing a counterexample to your statement: *there is* some $X$ and *some* $x$ so that the nearest neighbor is asymptotically a rational.

Comment: But the statement above is for a specified $X$. It doesn't seem surprising to me that the claim isn't true for all $X \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Then you should adjust your statement to reflect what you mean. This answer is a direct counterexample to the question posted.

Comment: I must be overlooking something. In your example you define $Z$ based on the $x$ chosen, so then how is that a counterexample to the statement where $Z \sim Uni[0,1]$?

Comment: @MONODA43 - Your OP conjecture is for _all_ laws $X,Y$ (meeting your criteria) and for _all_ irrational $x \in (0,1)$, something happens.  This answer exhibits specific examples of some triplet $(X,Y,x)$ (meeting your criteria) such that the something does not happen.  Therefore this is a counter-example.  The answer in fact includes infinitely many examples because it establishes the stronger claim that for _all_ $x$ there exists some $X$ s.t. $(X,Y,x)$ is a counter-example.  Does this help?

Comment: Thanks @antkam that adds some clarification for me. Although I'm still unclear how working with $Z$ supported on the rationals (as described in the answer) is the same as working with a uniform distribution.

Comment: @MONODA43 - $Z$ in the answer is only used in the case of $Y=1$, and even in that case, only half the time.  See the very first sentence of this answer.  I.e. (a) if $Y=0$ then $X \sim U[0,1]$, and (b) if $Y=1$ then flip another fair coin and, (b1) if heads, then $X$ is some (whatever) distribution on the rationals with positive prob for each rational, but (b2) if tails, then $X = Z$ as specified here.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help.

Comment: The problem with this construction is that in the 1-nearest neighbor analysis it is assumed that the distribution is "fixed", meaning that it does not change with n.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4366766/classification-of-rational-and-irrational-via-one-nearest-neighbor