# classification of rational and irrational via one-nearest neighbor

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, machine-learning, probability-limit-theorems

Consider the binary classification setting, where the input space is $[0,1]$ and the labels are $\{0,1\}$ Assume the distribution on the input-label $(X,Y)$ pair is as follows. Let $\Pr(Y=0)=\Pr(Y=1)=\frac{1}{2}$.  If $Y=0$, then the distribution of $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$. Then, if $Y=1$, the support of the distribution of $X$ is rational numbers in $[0,1]$ such that every rational number has a positive probability. Let $S_n=\{(X_1,Y_1),\dots,(X_n,Y_n)\}$ denotes $n$-iid samples from this distribution.

Fix an irrational $x \in [0,1]$. Consider the event $E_n$ which is the nearest point ( in usual distance) in $S_n$ to $x$ is a rational. We want to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Pr(E_n)=0$.

Note that the distribution on the input is fixed and does not change with $n$. This is Problem 5.38 from  Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition by Devroye, Györfi, and Lugosi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will prove the result under an additional hypothesis that $\mathbb E|Q-x|^{-2}<\infty$ where $Q$ has the same distribution as $X$ given $Y=1$ and $x$ is the fixed irrational number being considered. I believe this is a reasonable assumption since the authors themselves seem to have a specific distribution in mind which does satisfy this property, namely $I,J$ independent geometric random variables and $$
Q=\frac{\min(I,J)}{\max(I,J)},
$$
in which case all the negative moments $\mathbb E|Q-x|^{-k}<\infty$ exist, not just $k=2$.

Formally let $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite iid sequence with the given distribution. This allows us to consider the events $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as being defined on the same probability space. Thus by [Borel-Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_cantelli) it suffices to show that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(E_n)<\infty.
$$
Now we conclude using the same technique as Mike Earnest in the other partial answer by observing that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(E_n)&\leq n\ \mathbb P\left(Y_1=1\text{ and } |X_1-x|=\min_{1\leq i\leq n} |X_i-x|\right)\\
&\leq\sum_{q\in \mathbb Q}\mathbb P(X_1=q)\ n\left(1-\frac{|q-x|}{2}\right)^{n-1},
\end{align*}
thus by [Fubini-Tonelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) we have that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(E_n)&\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{q\in\mathbb Q}\mathbb P(X_1=q)\ n\left(1-\frac{|q-x|}{2}\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{q\in \mathbb Q}\mathbb P(X_1=q)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\left(1-\frac{|q-x|}{2}\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{q\in \mathbb Q}\mathbb P(X_1=q)\left(\frac{2}{|q-x|}\right)^2=4\mathbb E|Q-x|^{-2}.
\end{align*}

---

To justify my claim that something like this may have been what the authors had in mind, I share the following short snippets from page 80 of the text which sets the problem in context:
[image: geometric rational]
and further down on the page
[image: problem 5.38]

---

Lastly, while I am not sure if the claim is true without some negative moment condition on $Q$, I will point out that in general the [Hewitt-Savage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewitt%E2%80%93Savage_zero%E2%80%93one_law) zero-one law applies to the event $\{E_n\textrm{ occurs infinitely often}\}$, so even if Borel-Cantelli is insufficiently strong to show the bound, all that one needs to establish is that $\mathbb P(E_n\textrm{ occurs infinitely often})<1$ to conclude.

If one wanted to try to construct a counterexample to show that some moment condition is needed on $Q$, I suggest to start by looking at Marcus M's answer here: [classification of rational and irrational via one-nearest neighbor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4366766/classification-of-rational-and-irrational-via-one-nearest-neighbor)

Comment: Thanks @pre-kidney. Could you please hint on why the second moment assumption holds for the distribution considered by the authors? The rest of your proof seems correct to me.

Comment: Sure, although I limit myself to just a hint since it deserves to be its own (separate) question. Using brute force to calculate $\mathbb E|Q-x|^{-k}$ as a double sum, the inner sum has "closed form" as exponentially decaying term times values of Lerch zeta function. Plug in the "large $a$" asymptotic expansion from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Asymptotic_expansion to see that the Lerch gives a polynomial decay, which is dwarfed by the exponential terms. Summing such a series (outer sum) remains with exponential decay (times polynomial correction), hence finite sum.

Answer (score 2):

**Not a complete solution**

Let $q_1,q_2,\dots,$ be a complete list of the rational nubmers in $[0,1]$, and let $p_k=P(X=q_k\mid Y=1)$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
P(E_n)
&=P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n 
\{\text{$X_i\in \mathbb Q$ and $X_i$ is closest point to $x$}\}\right)
\\&\le nP(
\text{$X_1\in \mathbb Q$ and $X_1$ is closest point to $x$})
\\&= n\sum_{k=1}^\infty 
P(X_1=q_k)P\left(\bigcap_{j=2}^n\{|X_j-x|>|q_k-x|\}\right)
\\&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty 
\tfrac12\cdot p_k\cdot n\cdot P\left(|X_2-x|>|q_k-x|\right)^{n-1}
\end{align}
$$
We can write
$$
P(|X_2-x|>|q_k-x|)\le 1-\tfrac12|q_k-x|
$$
because for the complementary event that $X_2$ is *closer* to $x$ than $q_k$, a lower bound is the stricter event that $X_2$ is irrational and between $q_k$ and $x$, which occurs with probability $\frac12|q_k-x|$.

So far, we have the bound
$$
P(E_n)\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \tfrac12\cdot p_k\cdot n\cdot (1-\tfrac12 |q_k-x|)^{n-1}
$$
We would be done if we could use the Domintated Convergence THeorem to switch the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$. To do this, we need a dominating function, which is where I am stuck.

Comment: When you have the event Xi is closest rational you list all possible rational values, so Xi is a rational and multiply by the probability that Xi is the closest. For the latter you you multiply for each other sample element the probability that it is farther than Xi from x. Two questions. (1) don't you need and index i for q in all formulas ?

Comment: (2) don' you need to consider also the probability that the probability that the other samples are farther than Xi but rational as well ?

Comment: Third question actually (3) why the last summation goes up to n and not infinity? It should go up to all rational numbers, why do you have a sample size there?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the comments. (1) + (3) were typos. For (2), I made a logical error where I forgot to subtract from 1.  This is fixed, so the event that $X_i$ is rational and further is now accounted for. (Now, it is one minus ($X_i$ is irrational) and ($X_i$ is close), which becomes ($X_i$ is rational) or ($X_i$ is far) ).

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks for your answer. Your answer is almost correct imo. However, there are two issues:
1) The number of irrational points in $S_n$ is random distributed according to binomial with success rate 1/2 and number of trial $n-1$. Therefore, the step that you computed Pr(no other point is irrational and ...) should be revised. Also, if you fix $q_i$ then, the probability that irrational point does not closer to $x$ than $q_i$ is (1-2|x-q_i|). Please fix these two and I approve your nice answer.

Comment: Also you should consider that in the rest of points in $S_n$ there might be some rational point and you should compute the probability that these points are not closer than $q_i$ to $x$.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @Mahdi See edit for a simpler, better explained answer, if you are interested.

Comment: I am not sure that the bound P<1 that you have in the new version permits to apply the DCT since it is not uniform over k. Could you comment more on the DCT application?

Comment: @Thomas It is true in general that if $a_k$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $0\le a_k < 1$ for all $k$, and if $p_k$ is a sequence of nonnegative real numbers for which $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k=1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k (a_k)^{n-1}=0.$ This can be proven with DCT. If you cannot see how, you can ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Now I see it after reading your answer that you exploit also that the pk prefactors are positive and summable. Than it is clear, thanks for the clarification ! (+1)

Comment: @Thomas Still I can't see how to find the dominating function. Can you comment on that? thanks

Comment: Actually I am not sure I know. In the last comment of MikeEarnest one could use that $a_k^{n-1} \le 1$ to bound , but actually I notice now that in the answer there is an additional $n$ prefactor. I think MikeEarnest maybe is the one that should clarify the DCT application ?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Can you clarify on how to find the dominating function. It is not very clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahdi Wow, I now realize I am mistaken for a *third time* on this answer. The DCT part is incomplete as it stands, and I dont see an easy fix...

Comment: @Thomas I forgot about the $n$... I agree it is wrong, I don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not entirely sure if this is true in this exact wording.

This is not very formalized and thought trough, but consider a sequence $q_n\to x$ (monotonic) and $p_q$ so that $p_{q_{n+1}} \geq 2|q_n-q_{n+1}|$.

For example choose $p_{q_{n+1}} = 3|q_n-q_{n+1}| = \pm3(q_n-q_{n+1})$. The total propability is then
$$ p_{q_0}+\pm 3(q_0-x) $$
which can be chosen to be smaller than $1$. So this leads to a possible configuration.

If $X$ in uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ this means that
$$\mathbb P(|q_n-x| > |X-x| > |q_{n+1}-x|) < p_{n+1} $$
(in our case $=2/3 p_{n+1}$).

Under independence this means that
$$ \mathbb P(|X-x|<|q_n-x|) < \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty p_{q_k} $$

But this means that the expected time for the first occurance of something closer to $x$ than $q_n$ is expected to be smaller if $Y=1$ than if $Y=0$.

This should mean that it is highly probable that if the current closest hit is between the distance of $q_n$ and $q_{n+1}$ the next closer hit will most likely be with $Y=1$, so a rational number.

Of course I could be messing up something, but I do have some doubt that this is true. What can be said very easily though is that the set of $x$ for which this is not true is at most a set of measure $0$.